# Is there a way to get a drop-down hierarchical gantt in Deneb?

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, vega, gantt-chart, deneb

I've seen @david-bacci do some great work in Deneb . Specifically in this post [Deneb/Vega-Lite: Hierarchial y-axis on a Gantt chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111573/deneb-vega-lite-hierarchial-y-axis-on-a-gantt-chart)

I want to know though if it is possible to have those top categories be collapsable drop-down menus in Deneb?

Comment: It's possible but would require quite a bit of work to implement. I just created an org tree chart with collapsible nodes here which you can reference for ideas about how to approach this: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

Comment: @DavidBacci one thought if drop down can't happen is to layer behind each other with different opacities. Could this be an option? I'm not certain on the capabilities of deneb.

Comment: Most things are possible but they just takes time to implement. Don't forget you have slicers in PBI which you can use to show or hide datapoints if the chart gets too busy.

Answer (score 2):

The provided Vega Lite specification creates an interactive Gantt chart visualizing multiple projects divided into tasks with corresponding start and end dates, status ("Delayed", "Behind Schedule", "On Schedule"), and detailed descriptions.

The visualization is split into two main sections - a sidebar and the main chart area. The sidebar, created by "hconcat", contains an interactive list of project tasks, which are highlighted based on their selection state and their alignment with the current group. The main chart area, assembled by "vconcat", represents tasks' timelines as horizontal bars whose color corresponds to the task status.

Users can click on different tasks in the sidebar to view different timelines. The chart also includes a vertical rule indicating the current date and tooltips on the timeline bars providing detailed information.

[image]

```
{
 "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
 "data": {
 "values": [
 {
 "task": 0,
 "group": "P01",
 "name": "Clean the house",
 "start": "2023-03-10",
 "end": "2023-07-15",
 "status": "Project",
 "description": "This is the description of project 1."
 },
 {
 "task": 1,
 "group": "P01",
 "name": "House 1.1",
 "start": "2023-03-10",
 "end": "2023-04-15",
 "status": "Delayed",
 "description": "This is the description of project 2."
 },
 {
 "task": 2,
 "group": "P01",
 "name": "House 1.2",
 "start": "2023-04-15",
 "end": "2023-05-15",
 "status": "Behind schedule",
 "description": "This is the description of project 3."
 },
 {
 "task": 3,
 "group": "P01",
 "name": "House 1.3",
 "start": "2023-05-15",
 "end": "2023-07-15",
 "status": "On schedule",
 "description": "This is the description of project 3."
 },
 {
 "task": 0,
 "group": "P02",
 "name": "Clean the car",
 "start": "2023-06-10",
 "end": "2023-07-15",
 "status": "Project",
 "description": "This is the description of project 1."
 },
 {
 "task": 1,
 "group": "P02",
 "name": "Car 2.1",
 "start": "2023-04-10",
 "end": "2023-06-01",
 "status": "Delayed",
 "description": "This is the description of project 2."
 },
 {
 "task": 2,
 "group": "P02",
 "name": "Car 2.2",
 "start": "2023-07-01",
 "end": "2023-07-15",
 "status": "On schedule",
 "description": "This is the description of project 3."
 },
 {
 "task": 0,
 "group": "P03",
 "name": "Clean the garage",
 "start": "2023-03-10",
 "end": "2023-05-15",
 "status": "Project",
 "description": "This is the description of project 1."
 },
 {
 "task": 1,
 "group": "P03",
 "name": "Garage 3.1",
 "start": "2023-01-10",
 "end": "2023-02-01",
 "status": "Delayed",
 "description": "This is the description of project 2."
 },
 {
 "task": 2,
 "group": "P03",
 "name": "Garage 3.2",
 "start": "2023-02-04",
 "end": "2023-03-15",
 "status": "On schedule",
 "description": "This is the description of project 3."
 },
 {
 "task": 3,
 "group": "P03",
 "name": "Garage 3.3",
 "start": "2023-03-10",
 "end": "2023-04-01",
 "status": "Delayed",
 "description": "This is the description of project 2."
 },
 {
 "task": 4,
 "group": "P03",
 "name": "Garage 3.4",
 "start": "2023-05-04",
 "end": "2023-06-15",
 "status": "On schedule",
 "description": "This is the description of project 3."
 }
 ]
 },
 "hconcat": [
 {"height": 200, "width": 10, "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left"}},
 {
 "params": [
 {
 "name": "selectedgroup",
 "value": "P01",
 "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["group"]}
 }
 ],
 "transform": [
 {"calculate": "toDate(utcFormat(now(), '%Y-%m-%d'))","as": "currentDate"},
 {"calculate": "selectedgroup.group", "as": "pgroup"},
 {"calculate": "datum.group == datum.pgroup ? 'Y' : 'N'", "as": "check"},
 {"calculate": "datum.group == datum.pgroup ? 'A' : 'B'", "as": "sort"},
 {"calculate": "datum.sort + '-' + datum.group + '-0' + format(datum.task, '.0f') ","as": "project_sort"},
 {"calculate": "datum.group == datum.pgroup && datum.task == 0 ? '⯈' : datum.group !== datum.pgroup && datum.task == 0 ? '⭘' : ''","as": "icon"},
 {"calculate": "datum.icon + ' ' + datum.name + '|' + format(datum.task, '.0f') + '|' + datum.check", "as": "project_full_descr"},
 {"filter": "datum.group == datum.pgroup || datum.pgroup == null || datum.task == 0"}
 ],
 "width": 140,
 "height": {"step": 29},
 "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": false, "color": "transparent"},
 "encoding": {
 "y": {
 "field": "project_full_descr",
 "type": "nominal",
 "sort": {"field": "project_sort"},
 "axis": {
 "orient": "right",
 "domain": false,
 "grid": false,
 "ticks": false,
 "labels": true,
 "labelFontSize": { "expr": "indexof(datum.label, '|0') !== -1 && indexof(datum.label, '|Y') !== -1 ? 13: indexof(datum.label, '|0') !== -1 && indexof(datum.label, '|N') !== -1 ? 13: 12"
 },
 "labelPadding": { "expr": "indexof(datum.label, '|0') !== -1 ? -150:-120"
 },
 "labelExpr": "split(datum.label, '|')[0]", 
            "labelFontWeight": { "expr": "indexof(datum.label, '|0') !== -1 && indexof(datum.label, '|Y') !== -1 ? 'bold':'normal'"
 },
 "labelColor": { "expr": "indexof(datum.label, '|0') !== -1 && indexof(datum.label, '|Y') !== -1 ? '#000': indexof(datum.label, '|0') !== -1 && indexof(datum.label, '|N') !== -1 ? '#939191': '#E2E2E2'"
 }
 },
 "title": null
 }
 }
 },
 {
 "vconcat": [
 {"height": 10, "width": 10, "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left"}},
 {
 "width": 400,
 "height": {"step": 28},
 "transform": [
 {
 "calculate": "toDate(utcFormat(now(), '%Y-%m-%d'))",
 "as": "currentDate"
 },
 {
 "filter": {
 "and": [
 "datum['task'] != 0",
 {"and": [{"param": "selectedgroup"}]}
 ]
 }
 }
 ],
 "layer": [
 {
 "mark": {
 "type": "rule",
 "strokeDash": [2, 2],
 "strokeWidth": 1,
 "color": "#C690F1"
 },
 "encoding": {
 "x": {
 "field": "currentDate",
 "type": "temporal",
 "axis": {"format": "%d-%b"}
 }
 }
 },
 {
 "mark": {
 "type": "bar",
 "height": {"band": 0.4},
 "tooltip": true,
 "cornerRadius": 4
 },
 "encoding": {
 "y": {
 "field": "name",
 "type": "nominal",
 "axis": {
 "domain": false,
 "grid": false,
 "ticks": false,
 "labels": false
 },
 "title": null
 },
 "x": {
 "field": "start",
 "type": "temporal",
 "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
 "axis": {
 "format": "%d-%b",
 "domain": true,
 "grid": false,
 "ticks": true,
 "labels": true,
 "labelFontSize": 11,
 "labelColor": "#939191",
 "labelPadding": 5
 },
 "title": null
 },
 "x2": {"field": "end"},
 "color": {
 "title": null,
 "field": "status",
 "type": "nominal",
 "scale": {
 "domain": ["Delayed", "Behind schedule", "On schedule"],
 "range": ["#FAA43A", "#5DA5DA", "#60BD68"]
 },
 "legend": {
 "labelFontSize": 11,
 "labelColor": "#706D6C",
 "symbolType": "circle",
 "orient": "none",
 "direction": "horizontal",
 "legendY": 0,
 "legendX": 260
 }
 },
 "tooltip": [
 {
 "field": "start",
 "type": "temporal",
 "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
 "title": "Start"
 },
 {
 "field": "end",
 "type": "temporal",
 "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
 "title": "End"
 },
 {"field": "description", "type": "nominal", "title": "Descr."}
 ]
 }
 },
 {
 "mark": {
 "type": "text",
 "align": "left",
 "baseline": "middle",
 "dy": -11,
 "dx": 0,
 "color": "#000",
 "fontSize": 11
 },
 "encoding": {
 "x": {"field": "start", "type": "temporal"},
 "y": {"field": "name", "type": "nominal"},
 "text": {"field": "name", "type": "nominal"}
 }
 }
 ]
 }
 ]
 }
 ],
 "config": {"view": {"stroke": null}}
}
```

Adam