# How can you have multiple levels in an axis in vega-lite?

Tags: json, charts, visualization, vega-lite

Is it possible in Vega-Lite to have multiple (hierarchical) facets of a dimension on one axis or would that require Vega?

[image: Desired structure]

Best result I found so far was [concatenating the information](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgCMABj1L4NMljQA2fSDVJMKVKGJJBDOBDQBtUACEAkgH0AwnQAnmggAIIIEJhwAE5WCIogPr4AynBQmGwxof5IMa5KKWwMMVBwoQAqMDSyAARINNmFNjGYoQBMeu38Olo9WokAorJqHXoAHP39IAC+Cl5+gZgh6BFRsfGJyWkZWTl5BSBFJWWV1XUNTUctbeidWgDsU71DI2Ptfb3TcwsBwaFraJxJAJJTbdKZbLoXL5RLHUrldBVBgIJhwm5jLSfbGvUZ3XqmZ4DH5JRb-VaRIGbMF+HaQ0KeGgAaxccOKCLONXqjXReVuIE6nSJuPehK+LxJySWK3ClI2IK2tIhe3QjJZh3hpyRjFRvNamIAnMKlMM8QKdO0AMzCyVk5YAuXA0Gk1LKqHhHA4QSswrsrUgKpcy56-mCnTGkCm94AFht8xd0od6yditdu3dYU93o1fsRAfO3KuKQx+J0YpxJre+Kxcd+idVjVkNWMCppafpDfVbJOecDFx5zT5mPL00rZsF2O+8al5KSjebMFbLrpKo9Xp9R1zZxRaMH+vQWgNBtj4oGY9Ch4Nk1Ps2ndpl-jYODgskXZBfqZX7phOZ7nP7RYluap6jpGVbAWItYJrOj7Pq+SDvvIbZfvssK+n+2pBgO1xDviVoRlGeFGjetp-Pa0JPi+b4fshboMsyG6ar2BbBnuoZ6JOLznqWkEkXeZEPpR8GIZ+dGdoxW7ajuIZjDoxEVmB469NafF1rOAAiL6kFc4LpgCWYSRh+ZYYBuHmlovEKYR5nyd8AC6cwgJgMRILIEAAGZZAkqAeCAUCOFADCCNYeZWJgKKUDOyy1AA1LUADkCgJbFtRhRFumQiliXJXFaUIJQTFZfFiRIK40LBElX6VVuMx2UoyAxEyaCgMsz6hEweS3iAL5QGwajNs1IArKA7k0HAghmtKlVutVf5KDI+4gKVZQjANjkAB6DaN41msWQ5KK1ebRAgOBZI4XXre0W1jRNoRRjMD1AA), which is effective but way less appealing:

[image: All labels are repeated every row]

If I create row-facets, two problems arise: 1) I cannot nest facets, therefore this does not work for 3 or more aspects. 2) all labels are repeated even if there's no data, eg Copenhagen, Apples, Thin Air in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, using `hconcat` provided a (somewhate convoluted) solution combined with `lag` in `aggregate`.

Example: [like this](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAEIBJAPoBhOgE80IAIIIImOACdVCRSHMWAynBQmGzuDlZI7gZK-mwM7lBwDgAqMDSyAARINGEx6u6YDgBMAAwlRfwlAIyVVT4AorLKxWUAHLW1IAC+CqaWNpj26M6uHl4+foHBoeGR0SCx8YkpaZnZuQv5heilVQDsHdUNTS1FNdWdPX3Wdg4jbp5I3kqTQSFh6BFRPosJSeipBgIJg-LYtKrnSHHZo7aoANkOdSuvn6t2GLge4xelim7wcJhoAGt9D84n8VuksjlQZFtiBSqVEdDTgiLkdkX4BkMnBixk8Jji3jN0ATifNfssAYxgTSCuCAJxMpSNGH08oAZiZHNRgzuvMezxRASFHycOBwghJMTJkpAqUp61ldIZJSVIBVpwALFrekauXrRgaBcbpqbHObLeKbf87asqRt-GDYSVWVDlSdYRCfdd-SKcrJ0mQYPzsSG8XmxaSljH7WtqXlaeDU5106qGZDLr7OWjfPnC8XDa9Q3cI1aFtGVkCQQ25egqvL5d62XVWw55-L2svul2ddyrGwcHBZMWyEfg7jhSAvlHqxS6wmk2rly33Rmn2Js36e-vD8ekKf5FLC9TWvKtySlB1602RtYSKTUt1XWDFS3bUbl1T4DyPE8zyAk18SJMcJRrONHRnZ0yg7I5EPfT9u3Qq9ML-ADzzwitCInKUpydFoSmQtNXzbap4KhVDcxAAARI9SA2IdyzNC12NvCD724zMPwQgSFS1ABdHoMCgOQoDUIxQEwdwkFkCAADNQm8VBjBAf8yHcPg3CMbSlGcuIcCYIZDC-XVcOHa1b1030AHd0mUNhwpMkADwcdwYosWQpw8HwkAMdAkvC1LvGRBL0EEf8fCsmg4EEVU6PsJRMocHAXOIf0CpwBxirIUrysq-FBWCxyspABq4GIYDug8kAZFnByyoqqrd23UAZu6kVerxZEltVIixuRIzBCgBhirc9BJDYdIAApDFUTAgUoHK8oUDIrpu6qHqehBKFk0JXrUG6iO+673qGpq7H+m6geAjyMgAcgAHyhgBKDKBpy4l7C6cb4BoIttjEMolGQdxCTQUzbEPBwmEiHwQjYQRMBoVrUCsnQIDgJQDMES8zIsiAcEiI9Cj0o8DOUQtiZAIZFq61UUbgGqJtCbZJdmxKYry7cQDpzBLTQVLBEEWqAA8aCy0BouQdI0CZwQWc89waBhK2bY1mgoEJLLHdZkBiqYCr6gNhqHB54RMDOt7KG9iqHthhHDCqbSMgAXgTjIg7oUOfveiP9ehuH4cMT144AfmhqGMlQFOLTTsOs6j3PY+07ouib30ucsmz3DshynJcigjsMcavIYHy-ICuXPoTCcwtASKmhiuLCpAHKUrSjY6uy1WgQW+KGa9kqlA2nq0LltfBsa5rfQX9rOuVlayxmWqBvBvD0aUSbtmmqXD-PpXlqNUb1s-ugLa6Mdo6H2odGMJ1zqXQzrdDeCBQbvReo9WB49EGUD+iggGlAgZcnQU-UMkNo6IwfircKqMxpKExtjNAuMSj40iETTQGtSYxgphsamtN6aW2Zp7dmnNzKWV5i5WQAslBCzYCLWQHVmESxAAfde5DZY+DfmLBRi94Hq01trVAut9aOSNibFQbBzbyEZrwpQdNXbuwsbvH2gg-YB3QKnEO1ckD2NrjHOOidk4uPTtgmuOcY4FwyAAMlCRXYO-ibqBOIYYIo8ck6RKrrA2JdcxBFxLmXZJrjUnuMjkEvOCTG7N1MoI6ytk4rd1cv8futtvK+SMKPFifUtpTxADPaKsV7KgAXkvPKPtV7I00S1Nqe95GAOaaQ9AuDbijKKuM9R48kb1Uav-caqiekTJvs0gBOzll7N-sA9pu1wFqEgadWQF0w53SBOg5BYc0FYN+tGfBZ8QbPMBmsk0RDc4rMURQl+GA4BYywLQvGIACZMJJmTdA7CqZsBpnTBmHs2Y0wEdzYR-N1YSKkTI0Acj1Eyzlpsn+0sRmWLoDovRhtjZizNtkMxqLnbWJ4dbT2WdHGmj8W4jxhTDDqgbk3UpHT7b0DQK0CF1CwWoDoZY8p7dO6gFOQdc5DgoFXJgdgl6jzVpfTDkRDyxD-kaKUWjcaUKxaDFhSAeFVCQU0OYRTDMJRKBiD0q4JKxJybFVdiosybBiQAHUxUwDQK69UgtZDC1FrItRkziUqIVg4TKiQmii1pUY5y9s0BmT0JS12JgLKqjgAbNwoifBZxseyvS2j-h6L0gbeNOzEyNksawhwbgEA4FCDoDKhixbZodrYutDgACacBKbNxAAbIozbf4emFeNAysgyr4pACuoyisJq8ygLGkoeliDlW6ZLPWnbylYora-AN3rdEHUEMKoAA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "BI_City": "Amsterdam",
        "BI_Sector": "Cars",
        ...
        etc
        ...
        "Source": "Thin air",
        "Start": "2015-01-01",
        "End": "2019-01-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "transform": [
        {"aggregate": [], "groupby": ["BI_City", "BI_Sector", "Source"]},
        {
          "window": [
            {"op": "row_number", "as": "rownum"},
            {"op": "lag", "field": "BI_City", "as": "prevCity"},
            {"op": "lag", "field": "BI_Sector", "as": "prevSector"}
          ],
          "sort": [
            {"field": "BI_City"},
            {"field": "BI_Sector"},
            {"field": "Source"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "calculate": "join([datum.rownum, datum.BI_City, datum.BI_Sector, datum.Source, datum.prevCity, datum.prevSector], '|')",
          "as": "rowkey"
        }
      ],
      "height": 500,
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": false, "color": "transparent"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "rowkey",
          "sort": {"field": "rownum"},
          "title": null,
          "axis": {
            "domain": false,
            "grid": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labelExpr": "split(datum.label, '|')[1] == split(datum.label, '|')[4] ? '' : split(datum.label, '|')[1]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"aggregate": [], "groupby": ["BI_City", "BI_Sector", "Source"]},
        {
          "window": [
            {"op": "row_number", "as": "rownum"},
            {"op": "lag", "field": "BI_City", "as": "prevCity"},
            {"op": "lag", "field": "BI_Sector", "as": "prevSector"}
          ],
          "sort": [
            {"field": "BI_City"},
            {"field": "BI_Sector"},
            {"field": "Source"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "calculate": "join([datum.rownum, datum.BI_City, datum.BI_Sector, datum.Source, datum.prevCity, datum.prevSector], '|')",
          "as": "rowkey"
        }
      ],
      "height": 500,
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": false, "color": "transparent"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "rowkey",
          "sort": {"field": "rownum"},
          "title": null,
          "axis": {
            "domain": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labelExpr": "split(datum.label, '|')[1] == split(datum.label, '|')[4] && split(datum.label, '|')[2] == split(datum.label, '|')[5] ? '' : split(datum.label, '|')[2]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"aggregate": [], "groupby": ["BI_City", "BI_Sector", "Source"]},
        {
          "window": [
            {"op": "row_number", "as": "rownum"},
            {"op": "lag", "field": "BI_City", "as": "prevCity"},
            {"op": "lag", "field": "BI_Sector", "as": "prevSector"}
          ],
          "sort": [
            {"field": "BI_City"},
            {"field": "BI_Sector"},
            {"field": "Source"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "calculate": "join([datum.rownum, datum.BI_City, datum.BI_Sector, datum.Source, datum.prevCity, datum.prevSector], '|')",
          "as": "rowkey"
        }
      ],
      "height": 500,
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": false, "color": "transparent"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "rowkey",
          "sort": {"field": "rownum"},
          "title": null,
          "axis": {
            "domain": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labelExpr": "split(datum.label, '|')[3]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "width": 800,
      "height": 500,
      "transform": [
        {
          "calculate": "join([datum.BI_City,datum.BI_Sector,datum.Source],'|')",
          "as": "rowkey"
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "height": {"band": 0.5},
        "stroke": "black",
        "strokeWidth": 0.3
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "rowkey",
          "sort": "ascending",
          "axis": {"grid": true, "tickBand": "extent", "labels": false},
          "title": null
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Start",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"grid": false, "title": "Year"}
        },
        "x2": {"field": "End"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "concat": {"spacing": 0},
    "view": {"fill": "transparent", "stroke": null}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, follow the example listed in the docs here:

[image]

[Example](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#example-conditional-axis-properties-and-multi-line-axis-label)

Comment: Thanks! I saw this one, but it is limited to a horizontal axis, since it uses newlines to format. I tried using tabs to achieve the same effect for a vertical axis, to no avail.

Comment: Possible achievable with some hconcats. Here is a good solution you could build from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76327701/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-drop-down-hierarchical-gantt-in-deneb

Comment: Thanks! I managed to achieve 80% of the desired tesult by using 4 hconcats and conditional labels using lag/lead. Each label-level is a seperate view.

Comment: Good work. Don't forget to add your solution so it can be marked as solved and/or upvote the answers that you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a trellis grid could be suitable here?

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "BI_City": "Amsterdam",
        "BI_Sector": "Cars",
        "Source": "Thin air",
        "Start": "2002-01-01",
        "End": "2008-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Amsterdam",
        "BI_Sector": "Cars",
        "Source": "Thin air",
        "Start": "2017-01-01",
        "End": "2021-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Amsterdam",
        "BI_Sector": "Cars",
        "Source": "Thumb",
        "Start": "2011-01-01",
        "End": "2016-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Amsterdam",
        "BI_Sector": "Bikes",
        "Source": "Thin air",
        "Start": "2020-01-01",
        "End": "2026-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Amsterdam",
        "BI_Sector": "Bikes",
        "Source": "Thumb",
        "Start": "2019-01-01",
        "End": "2023-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Amsterdam",
        "BI_Sector": "Apples",
        "Source": "Thin air",
        "Start": "2020-01-01",
        "End": "2024-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Amsterdam",
        "BI_Sector": "Apples",
        "Source": "Thin air",
        "Start": "2006-01-01",
        "End": "2011-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Birningham",
        "BI_Sector": "Bikes",
        "Source": "Thin air",
        "Start": "2016-01-01",
        "End": "2021-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Birningham",
        "BI_Sector": "Apples",
        "Source": "Thumb",
        "Start": "1994-01-01",
        "End": "1998-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Copenhagen",
        "BI_Sector": "Cars",
        "Source": "Thin air",
        "Start": "2001-01-01",
        "End": "2005-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Copenhagen",
        "BI_Sector": "Cars",
        "Source": "Thin air",
        "Start": "2023-01-01",
        "End": "2029-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Copenhagen",
        "BI_Sector": "Bikes",
        "Source": "Thin air",
        "Start": "2001-01-01",
        "End": "2005-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Copenhagen",
        "BI_Sector": "Bikes",
        "Source": "Thumb",
        "Start": "2009-01-01",
        "End": "2013-01-01"
      },
      {
        "BI_City": "Denver",
        "BI_Sector": "Apples",
        "Source": "Thin air",
        "Start": "2015-01-01",
        "End": "2019-01-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  "width": 120,
  "spacing": 5,
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Start",
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {"grid": false, "domain": false},
      "title": null
    },
    "x2": {"field": "End", "title": null},
    "color": {
      "field": "Source",
      "type": "nominal",
      "legend": {"orient": "bottom", "titleOrient": "left"},
      "title": ""
    },
    "opacity": {"value": 0.5},
    "column": {
      "field": "BI_City",
      "title": "",
      "header": {"labelAngle": 0, "labelPadding": 0}
    },
    "row": {
      "field": "BI_Sector",
      "title": "",
      "header": {"labelAngle": 0, "labelPadding": 0}
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "BI_City", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "BI_Sector", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Source", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Start", "type": "temporal"},
      {"field": "End", "type": "temporal"}
    ]
  }
}
```